# javascript library SheetJS. Pass string into excel parce function

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

I am using SheetJS library to parse xlsx file with javascript.
The way i got the file force me to pass received data as string into the javascript function.
Now I confused how do i pass the string into XLSX.utils.sheet_to_txt. What type of convertion should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The solution has found.
The string was converted to hex and converted back to array